# How to convert json with jarray inside to a object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following classes

```
public class Test
{
    public string name;

    public List<Field> fields;
}

public class Field
{
    public string id;

    public string name;
}
```

and the following Json

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "fields": [
    {
       "id": "4786182461",
       "name": "field1",
    },
    {
       "id": "41241241122",
       "name": "field2",
    },
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to convert this json to the Test object, the following code convert properly the "name", but the "fields" always returns null.

```
Test returnTest = JObject.Parse(json).ToObject<Test>()
```

Any ideas about how I can make the "fields" return the array?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the standard `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json)`?  And public Fields are typically a big no-no, you should be using properties.

Comment: I tried also the standard one, was giving me the same problem. Now is working fine, I still don't know what was going on... And thank you for the advice about the properties!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fvbGQX):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json = "{\"name\": \"name1\",\"fields\": [{\"id\": \"4786182461\",\"name\": \"field1\",},{\"id\": \"41241241122\",\"name\": \"field2\",}, ]}";
    
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
    
    Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name;
    
    public List<Field> Fields;
}

public class Field
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

Result:

> name1
>
> 2

However, I'd highly recommend you stick with best practices and use properties, for example:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```